# How does Array.map() works with react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, I am working on a school project. In it, I am using `Array.map` method to render my component in DOM. It's working fine but I have a little confusion with `map()` method on the array. When I was learning Javascript I used  `Array.map` and I was storing a new Array from `map()` method into a variable. for example `const newArray = Array.map(e => e*2)`. So from MDN documents, I know map returns a new array. So now in react I saw some example and they are not storing `Array.map` result in a new variable so where is this new array exist after mapping the old array, which got modified, they are just using `Array.map(e => e*2)` not storing returned new array in any variable? For an example below where are they storing returned new array after mapping on `incompleteTodos`.

So, Am I missing something here from Array.map method?
P.S Below code is working fine.

```
const incompleteTodos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
<div className="todos">
          {incompleteTodos.length > 0 && <h2 className="incomplete">Incomplete</h2> }
          {
            incompleteTodos.map(todo => (
              <Todo key={todo.id} removeTodo={this.removeTodo} completeTodo={this.completeTodo} todo={todo}/>
            ))
          }
```

Comment: in JSX, you can add `html element`, `string`,  and  `array of element or string`. Here you ` incompleteTodos.map` returning `array of  Todo `. thats why we don't need to store it in another variable

Comment: for reference check https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children

Comment: Check out this one as well, https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing variable automatically is programmed inside `render()` function in JSX it works. This is the special of the ReactJS that refrained of creating too much variable for using. So if you have the code like this:

```js
render() {
    return(
        <h1>{1+1}</h1>{// It will print '2' on the browser}
    );

}
```

But the way using `Array.map()` as a variable still decent and acceptable but the code you showed above seems better to work with react code so don't worry about that.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const myTodos = [<div>Hi1</div>,<div>Hi2</div>,<div>Hi3</div>,]
// Created a array to return

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {myTodos}
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default App;
```

Here is the link for more reference, reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method is indeed returning an array of `Todo` components. This array is used by React to render the items.

The code you posted is equivalent to:

```
const incompleteTodos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
const items = incompleteTodos.map(todo => (
    <Todo key={todo.id} removeTodo={this.removeTodo} completeTodo={this.completeTodo} todo={todo} />
));

<div className="todos">
    {incompleteTodos.length > 0 && <h2 className="incomplete">Incomplete</h2> }
    {items}
```